# Utilize my android tablet for actionscript 3 programming

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

Anyone know of a way to setup an android tablet to allow for programming and testing of flash apps?

Something similar to like the FlashDevelop environment in Windows?

Comment: This is *off-topic* please read the [FAQ]. This should be posted on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and yes the odds of that question getting burned and closed is quite high...

Comment: And furthermore - fwiw, flash is no longer supported on Android :)

Comment: I don't see why this is off-topic, it's about developing *on* a Android device, not about developing *for* a Android device.

Comment: I agree with Flow.

Comment: @t0mm13b bad form. I don't wish to develop for android as Flow has stated. I just have a tablet, and I program in AS3 for facebook apps, so I wish to know if the tablet is capable of utilizing some tools to allow me to program with what I want on it and to be able to compile and test as well. And let's not forget that older Android OS versions do support flash. Let's not keep our minds inside the box shall we?

Comment: I concur with Flow and Al -- trouble is the *tag*, which clearly screems "OT", the question itself fits here :) So it needs someone who already did this (and a neutral tag ;)

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even notice the tags... I had 5 tags on this prior to it being migrated. Let me fix that. EDIT: there's not really any tags that I can use that relates to my question that I've tried inputting...